# How to create Compiler warning for my function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to validate my inputs to function with some conditions and show as a compiler warning/error.

How it is possible?

For example:

```
func getPoints(start: Int, end: Int) {

}
```

I want to show compiler warning/error when someone tries to give input high for start than end.

```
getPoints(start: 3, end: 10) // No warnings
getPoints(start: 6, end: 2) // Compiler warning like: end value can not be less than start value
```

Actually this is for a framework purpose. I want to ensure that the parameters are not bad inputs.

Answer (score 3):

Such a constraint can't be enforced at compile time. Take `Range` for example, which enforces that the `lowerBound` always compares as less or equal to the `upperBound`. That's just an assertion that runs at run-time, and crashes if it's not met.

I would suggest you just change your API design to use a `Range<Int>` or `ClosedRange<Int>` taking pairs of `Int`s to model ranges is a bad idea, for many reasons:

1. It doesn't communicate the semantics of a range. Two integers could be anything, but a range is something much more specific.
2. It doesn't have any of the useful methods, like `contains(_:)`, or support for pattern matching via the `~=` operator.
3. Its error prone, because when passing pairs around, you might make a copy/paste error leading you to accidentally use the same param twice.
4. It reads better: `getPoint(3...10)`

Comment: I'm making a framework. So I need to validate the inputs to function. So that framework will be error prone

Comment: It doesn't matter where this Swift code resides. Whether it's on an iOS app, a mac CLI app, a linux sever backend, a library or on punchcards, Swift doesn't allow you to make static assertions/warnings/errors about values of data, only their types. The feature you're reaching for is called "dependant" typing, which lets things like integer values be generic params, that lets you reason about values as types at compile time. C++ has it. It's pretty compelx to use, but it's there. Swift doesn't have it.

Comment: Enforcing constraints at run time doesn't make your framework error prone. You want code to error out when it tries to do something invalid. If a client of your framework broke its API contract, by providing a larger arg before the smaller arg, then that's *on them*. Erroring out *is the correct thing to do*, to stop further program progress (in this ill-defined state, which could eventually lead you to mishandle data, cause data loss by saving unknowingly corrupted data, etc.). It also fails loudly, so that the library clients will notice the bug, test their code, and fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't generate a warning at compile time, since the arguments are not evaluated beyond checking for type conformance.

In your example, you have used constants, so it would, in theory, be possible to perform the check you want, but what if you passed a variable, or the result of another function?  How much of your code would the compiler need to execute in order to perform the check?

You need to enforce your requirements at run time.  For example, you could have your function `throw` if the parameters were incorrect:

```
enum MyErrors: Error {
     case rangeError
}

func getPoints(start: Int, end: Int) throws {
    guard start <= end else {
        throw MyErrors.rangeError
    }
    ...
}
```

Or you could have the function simply handle the problem:

```
func getPoints(start: Int, end: Int) {
     let beginning = min(start,end)
     let ending = max(start,end)
     ...
}
```

Also, I recommend Alexander's suggestion of using `Range` instead of `Int`; it is always a good idea to take advantage of Foundation types, but I will leave my answer as it shows some approaches for handling issues at runtime.